# Create a custom layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, customization, keras-layer, tf.keras

I am trying to create a Sign layer in tensorflow.
Because the gradient of Sign is zero, I want to create a function like this:

[image]

but I don't know where should write backward function?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this can be done via [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient). This allows you to write a forward function along with a custom gradient function which depends on the "incoming" gradients (from the layers further down the model) as well as the forward function.

With it, you could create a function like this:

```
@tf.custom_gradient
def sign_with_grad(x):
    output = tf.sign(x)
    def grad_fn(dy):
        check_range = tf.where(tf.less_equal(tf.abs(x), 1.), 1., 0.)
        return dy*check_range
    return output, grad_fn
```

Here, we write a custom gradient that simply passes through that of the layer above -- except that it zeros out all elements where the input is outside the range [-1, 1]. We return both the result of the forward function (the sign) as well as the gradient function itself. The decorator takes care of handling the rest.

Please note, I did not check whether the code runs -- let me know if it doesn't! In particular, the `less_equal` and or `where` checks might need explicit broadcasting -- e.g. use `tf.ones_like(x)` instead of `1.` (same for 0).

Comment: In that case, please consider upvoting & accepting the answer so that other people can see.